# Is there a Safari Extension for adding Mail-style Data Detectors to Web Pages?

Tags: safari, ical, safari-extensions

I love the Data Detectors in Apple Mail. Open a message that has a date or time in the content, and creating a new Calendar event is a snap. But this feature is not in Safari, so I'm wondering if there is a way to get it in there? An extension perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the HTML `<address>`-[Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_address.asp) and [hCard](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard), which are supported by Safari and are used for semantic data. Unfortunately, there is no data detector in Safari for those standards.

There is a [workaround](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071108065202610), until those detectors are implemented, by using "Mail Contents of This Page" from the File menu.