# Data detector for Safari similar to Mail.app?

Tags: macos, safari, mail.app

Does Safari have a similar data detector system like Mail.app? I don't think it has this because I am trying to add an event based on date and it doesn't occur. Is the data detector system limited on Safari compared to the Mail app?

Answer (score 1):

Safari only supports the telephone data detector.

It's currently not possible to enable the other data detectors in Safari. ([Is there a Safari Extension for adding Mail-style Data Detectors to Web Pages?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/35854/37797))